# How to measure declination of sun and moon?

Tags: astronomy, measurements, sun, moon

I came by some graphs showing the declination for sun and moon (between angles of -30° and +30°). The graphs look very much like sine waves.

I googled a bit and read about what the declination is, and I found tools to look up the declination for a certain date. However, what I really haven't understood yet is, how to measure the declination. So if I would like to create such a graph during the next 365 days by hand, what exactly would I measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd wait till the sun was at the highest point in the sky for the day, and measure the angle it makes with the vertical.

Comment: If you measure both parameters you can make a solar Analemma like the ancients: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma

Comment: are there any tools to precisely measure the angle (is a sextant the right tool for that?)

Comment: @navige: a sextant would definitely work.  Make sure to have a filter on it so the sun doesn't blind you.

Answer (score 2):

Plant a stick in the ground vertically (use a level). Length of shadow / length of pole = tan (declination).

Declination is the angle the sun makes with the zenith (direction pointing upwards--the stick's axis)